# Programmatical and application-based editing of an Excel file

Tags: vb.net, excel, stream, locking

Good evening,

I have the following problem to solve:

I want to add to an Excel file the contents of a bunch of user-generated `.txt` files. These files are generated throughout the day and sent over FTP to a folder, which is being constantly monitored by the program to see if there are new additions. 
If the program finds new `.txt` files in it, it opens the Excel file which is to be edited, adds the info and then closes the Excel, saving the changes.

At the same time, users have to open these Excel files to check the new updated info and deal with it accordingly.

The program's execution is somewhat like this:

1. Infinite loop checking if the folder is empty or contains new `.txt` files.
2. If the folder is not empty (hence there is info to be added), it checks whether the Excel file is open or not.
3. If the Excel file is closed:

   1. Opens it programmatically and adds the info to it.
   2. Saves the Excel file and quits.
   3. Backups the `.txt` to another folder in case there was some sort of error.
4. If the Excel file is open:

   1. Keep checking until it is closed.

To check if the folder is empty or not I use: `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any()`

To check if the Excel file is open I use: 
`System.IO.FileInfo(path)` and a `FileStream` which, inside a Try-Catch clause, opens the `FileInfo` in the following mode: `info.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)`

For the opening, editing and saving/closing of the Excel file I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`, `[..].Workbook` and `[..].Worksheet`.

The main problem comes when a user opens (through the normal Office Application) the Excel file in the middle of the addition process. I was hoping to find some sort of lockage of said file so the user cannot interrupt the editing process.

Any ideas on how to combine both types of opening/editing the Excel file?

Thank you so much in advanced.

**TL;DR: How can I prevent, programmatically, a user from opening an Excel file while a program is editing that very Excel? Or at least, open another instance of it so the process is not interrupted?**

PS: If any further code should be needed, I'll gladly post it :)

Comment: I could be wrong here, but doesn't excel automatically create locks when a file is open for modification? something like ~{DiscombobulatedFileNameHere}.xlsx, Could you recreate that same file temporarily then remove it when your process finishes?

Comment: What I would do in your situation is: 1. program copies the given Excel file to a temporary location (don't need to check if it is being used or not); 2. perform all the edits. 3. Once the edits are done, the program will intend to delete the original version of the file (being accessed by users); it would try for as long as required until finding a moment when no user is accessing it; right after deleting the file, copies the new modified one there. In this way, you would make sure that users will not interrupt the edition process at all.

Comment: You can set the file as "read only", but I would expect (if you're using Excel automation to add the data) that this should already be taken care of by Excel.  If you're not using excel to add the data, what are you using?  Whatever you use should also lock the file, since it needs to open it for writing.

Comment: @varocarbas - what if a user makes a change while the program is adding data to the copy? Now you have to merge the changes in both copies...

Comment: @TimWilliams good point. So better moving the file at the start, instead of copying it. Users shouldn't be able to access the file while it is being updated by the program. Interop communication is not compatible with user access.

Comment: Are users going to be adding/editing data that your process entered?  Or are they going to just be adding data elsewhere in the workbook?  If your input and the user's input are in different cells, maybe a Shared Workbook would be useful?

Comment: Hello to all, couldn't check the answers yesterday. First off, thanks for the replies.
The users WILL be editing the data contained in the Excel (mainly just adding if the lines were dealt with and by whom. No new lines, however they need to see which ones have been checked. 
The idea of trying to move, add info to it and then move it back seems to be the way to go, since Varocarbas pointed out there's no compatibility between `Interop` and user access. 

Still it seems weird that there's no file-attribute modification of some sort to prevent user access from editing the file...

Comment: Is it a shared workbook? Is it possible to unshare it while making the changes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a better solution. It sounds like you are maxing out the capabilities of Excel. You would be better off, if possible, to use a database.